# Trying to get a div in to view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to get a div in to the view and the div elements are being added dynamically.. so i am assigning a link with which on click a div element can be brought in to the view no matter if it is already in view. so when i click on the link, if the div im trying to get to the view is already in view, it will go away from my view. is it a bug??

http://jsfiddle.net/xFu3M/6/

Ive added a working example.

the code goes like

```
$(".testClick").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
      // Call the scroll function
    goToByScroll("indID"+1);
});


function goToByScroll(id){
      // Reove "link" from the ID
    id = id.replace("link", "");
      // Scroll
    $('.contentBody').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
        'slow');
 }
```

Comment: what do u mean by `it will go away from my view`... i didn't see aything u said in the provided fiddle...

Comment: the link which we are clicking stays the same

Comment: then u didnt try clicking on the link... by clicking on the link, im trying to get div 1 in to view.. since div1 is already in view..the div6 comes in to view on click

Comment: the link is  "testClick"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to take in consideration the parent offset too:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xFu3M/11/)**</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wrapper").css({"width" : $(window).width() , "height" :  $(window).height()} );  
    $(".testClick").on("click",function(e){      
        e.preventDefault(); 
        goToByScroll("indID1"); // try change to indID4
    });       
});

function goToByScroll(id){
    var el = $('#'+id);
    var elOffs = el.offset().top;
    var parOffs = el.closest('.contentBody').offset().top;
    $('.contentBody').stop().animate({ scrollTop: elOffs - parOffs },800);
}
```